# If there is two consecutive joins, what is the input of the second one in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

At the first I have three tables:

> - EMPLOYEE HAS CONNECTION WITH TRIP TABLE.   
>    TRIP HAS CONNECTION    WITH DRIVER TABLE

I want list of all truck which are and are not in the trip table and also name of the drivers in driver table.

```
SELECT TRUCK.REG# , DRIVER.L#
FROM TRUCK
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP
ON TRUCK.REG# = TRIP.REG# 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRIVER
ON DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#
;
```

The first part is all the truck which are in the trip table either are not in the trip table.

```
SELECT TRUCK.REG# , DRIVER.L#
FROM TRUCK
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP
ON TRUCK.REG# = TRIP.REG#
```

I think oracle makes a TEMPORARY TABLE OF ALL TRUCK WITH TRIP and then that is input to the second part which is:

LEFT OUTER JOIN DRIVER
ON DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#

And it is list of all the truck which are in trip table and trip table has driver in driver table.
Is this right?

Now if we add one more table EMPLOYEE and we want to get name of the drivers. I again left outer join it to EMPLOYEE which is:

```
SELECT TRUCK.REG# , DRIVER.L#
FROM TRUCK
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP
ON TRUCK.REG# = TRIP.REG# 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRIVER
ON DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE
ON EMPLOYEE.E# = DRIVER.E#
;
```

At the end, is there any difference between ORACLE AND SQL that how they treat sql commands?

Comment: Look at each join sequentially. Each table joins just to where you specify it, either to the first table, or one of the other tables.

Comment: By 'SQL' do you mean SQL Server? And why does the title ask about inner joins when you're only using outer joins? You can see how Oracle is choosing to join by looking at the execution plan.

Comment: You do not need to concern yourself with _how_ the results are obtained unless you are doing performance tuning. You should only be worried about _what_ results you will get from your SQL. Whether Oracle makes an invisible temporary table, or accesses the data through a particular index is not relevant to the result. </>


To answer your final question, every database has it's own dialect (version) of SQL. Some are more similar than others, but they are all slightly different. You need to know the syntactical idiosyncrasies of the database you are working with to make the most of it.

Comment: However, if you use the most common SQL statements and predicates (in the ANSI SQL standard), your SQL will work with most databases and be most understandable to others. Statements such as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are common to all SQL databases, and should give the same result on Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can know what Oracle did is run it while the session is being traced, and examined the explain plan given in there (on 11g and above there a few easier ways to do it, look at the columns you have within V$SESSION).

You can also ask the database to show you the explain plan for the query, most of the chances (more than 90%) you'll get the right execution plan that the DBMS runs for this query.

Notice that there is no "right" answer. Oracle uses its statistics to build execution plans, and as long as the final result is correct - Oracle will use the most efficient method (which might mean the complete opposite order than the intuitive one).

What I am trying to say - no one here could tell you what's the "internal" or "external" tables in a join, only the engine can - since it depends on the current statistics that it holds.
In the case of multiple left outer joins, the order for correctness has to be specific one, but not across the tables (for example 1 left outer join 2 left outer join 3 might work as 2 and 3, and than 1 - or 1 and 2 and than 3).